# c# monogame 3d render billboard always facing camera with ability to rotation along X axis

Tags: c#, math, monogame, hlsl

I'm programming a 3D game in C# monogame, and I would like the particles to always face the camera. The code below works for that. I only send the particles texture, size and rotation to HLSL, which allows me to calculate the corners on the GPU.

**This is the code that works without the particles rotating**

**output.PositionWS** is the vertex world position

**CameraPosWS** is the camera world position

**size.x** is just the X size of billboard

**size.y** is just the Y size of the billboard

```
output.PositionWS = mul(float4(input.inPositionOS, 1), World).xyz;
float3 ParticleToCamera = output.PositionWS - CameraPosWS;
float3 ParticleUp = float3(0, 0, 1);
float3 ParticleRight = normalize(cross(ParticleToCamera, ParticleUp));

finalPosition.xyz += ((input.inTexCoords.x - 0.5f) * size.x) * ParticleRight;
finalPosition.xyz += ((0.5f - input.inTexCoords.y) * size.y) * ParticleUp;
```

But I would like the particle to now rotate while still always facing the camera. I was thinking of using a matrix to transform the calculated corners of the billboard to rotate the billboard, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

**This is the code with billboard rotation along the X axis which doesn't work**

**rotation** is a rotation in radians

```
float3 ParticleToCamera = output.PositionWS - CameraPosWS;
float3 ParticleUp = float3(0, 0, 1);
float3 ParticleRight = normalize(cross(ParticleToCamera, ParticleUp));

float3x3 RotationMatrix = float3x3(
ParticleRight,
ParticleUp,
ParticleToCamera
);

float3 rotatedVertex = mul(float3(input.inPositionOS.xy, 0), RotationMatrix);

// Only apply rotation on the X axis
rotatedVertex.x = rotatedVertex.x * cos(rotation);

finalPosition.xyz += ((input.inTexCoords.x - 0.5f) * size.x) * rotatedVertex.x;
finalPosition.xyz += ((0.5f - input.inTexCoords.y) * size.y) * rotatedVertex.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this problem. The point of the Vertex shader is to transform from and object/world coordinate system into screen based coordinate system.

The orientation is already screen aligned.

I will assume that scaling is accounted for in the `size` variable. Otherwise, scale it using `ParticleToCamera.z`.

Please note the following code is incomplete without the initial `finalPosition` definition: I have assumed it to be `PositionWS`.

```
output.PositionWS = mul(float4(input.inPositionOS, 1), World).xyz;
float3 ParticleToCamera = output.PositionWS - CameraPosWS;
float3 ParticleUp = float3(0, 0, 1);
float3 ParticleRight = float3(1, 0, 0);

finalPosition.xyz += ((input.inTexCoords.x - 0.5f) * size.x) * ParticleRight;
finalPosition.xyz += ((0.5f - input.inTexCoords.y) * size.y) * ParticleUp;
```